# Counting-Box problem-finding a conditional subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a) for how many integers between 1,000 and 9,999 is the sum of the digits exactly 9?

$n=8;k=4; $ ${n+k-1\choose k-1} = {11 \choose 3} = 165$

b) For how many of the integers from part a) have all nonzero integers?

I have no idea how to solve this- my problem solving approach for most of these have been to identify symbolic distinguishable "boxes" and symbolic indistinguishable "items" and arrange n and k as needed. Not sure how this changes when you want to identify this conditional subset.

thanks in advance for any insight

edit (n was 9, should've be 8)

Comment: I don't think you're counting all of the numbers in part $a$, because $5004$ and $4005$ are different numbers.

Comment: I think the answer to a) may not be quite right.

Comment: Answer is right (at least it matches what was in the back of the textbook I am using) but I did put the wrong n down at first. Any ideas on how to approach part b?

Comment: Define "sum of digits". Do you calculate it repetitively until it reaches a single digit?

Comment: sum of digits=thousands place number+hundreds place number +...

Comment: ex: 4005 =9; 4311=9, etc.